# How to add timestamp to every document inserted in firecloud

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

> I want to add timestamp to every inserted documents in my cloud firebase on load window

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
   const data = {
      pepe:10,
      popo:11,
      bobo:12
    };

   const res = db.collection('Group').doc("I want to add timestamp here as document").set(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use firestore Timestamp class, `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()` 
The reason being:
 `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` does not work with `add` method from firestore. 
Also, don't forget to add

1. `const firebase = require('firebase-admin')` on top of index.js
2. dependency `firebase-admin` in package.json
   Also for reference visit: [How to set Firestore serverTimestamp on document create](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/736#issuecomment-438943257)

Comment: where exactly to put the firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()? to be a document to my collection

Comment: const res = db.collection('Group').doc(id).set({data, createdOn: db.firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()}); You can refer to: https://labs.thisdot.co/blog/storing-your-notes-in-the-cloud-firestore-with-vuejs for further explanation and reference.

Comment: And what if i want to read sensor value and put it as data in my  firecloud  window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
   var database = firebase.database();
         var Sensor;
database.ref().on("value", function(snap){
 Sensor= snap.val().Sensor;
});
});
const data = {
      sensor: Sensor;
    };

   const res = db.collection('Group').doc("yes").set(data);
});